# Applet live streaming through webcam on server

Tags: java, applet, streaming, webcam, live

I want to embed a live streaming panel into applet.

after searching i found:

- JMF.. but found that it's very old (2002) & needs 32bit version of JDK & JRE which isn't available as the applet contains another components previously written.
- Xuggler.. but i found that it lacks good support for capture live stream from webcam.

So, is there another library or project to reach my goal?

Thanks in Advance,
Ali Zein

Comment: Did you have a look at [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) ?

Comment: Not yet, I'll have look on it.
Thanks